# How to get the External IP Address with in the LAN?

Tags: asp.net

I want to get the External IPAddress of the client system in the LAN. My server is their in LAN so nd I make a request to the server through my local systems at the time I need that local system External IP Address through ASP.NET  but it is giving the local IPAddress.

Comment: if you have internet connection, make a connection to sites like http://www.whatsmyip.us/ , and then filter the HTML results to get the external IP

Comment: but it excute at server side so its give server IPAddress only but we need user machine Public IPAddress is their any chance to excute this type of code from javascript if it is their pls tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this programmatically without visiting some external tool, or getting support from your router. ghostdog has a good suggestion.